# Display image through html image element object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code :

```
function createImage(source) {                
var pastedImage = new Image();                
pastedImage.onload = function() {
                    
}
pastedImage.src = source;
}
```

The function `createImage` contain the source parameter which contain the source of an image. After that I created the object `pastedImage` of class `Image` and after alerting that I am getting the html image element object like `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

My question is how I can display image into my html page using that object. I want to display it after `onload` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can do like this :

```
    function createImage(source) {
        var pastedImage = new Image();
        pastedImage.onload = function() {

 document.write('<br><br><br>Your image in canvas: <img src="'+pastedImage.src+'" height="100" width="200"/>');                      

        }
        pastedImage.src = source;        
    }​
```

Answer (score 4):

Hiya : **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wXV3u/

Api used = `.html` http://api.jquery.com/html/

In demo click on the `click me` button.

Hope this helps! Please lemme know if I missed anything! B-)

**Code**

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    createImage("http://images.wikia.com/maditsmadfunny/images/5/54/Hulk-from-the-movie.jpg");

});

function createImage(source) {
    var pastedImage = new Image();
    pastedImage.onload = function() {

    }
    pastedImage.src = source;
    $(".testimonialhulk").html(pastedImage);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, and better, using javascript dom primitive (replaceChild):

Get the parent of the image, the div or span that contains it, and replace the old img tag with the new image object you created with your function

```
 var domImgObj = document.getElementById("image");

 var imgObj = createImage(src); // your function
 imgObj.id = pageimgObj.id; // necessary for future swap-outs

 document.getElementById("container").replaceChild(imgObj,domImgObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

> document.[createRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange).[createContextualFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment)(img.outerHTML)

### Example

```js
const img = new Image()
img.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico"
const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`${img.outerHTML}`)
document.querySelector(`body`).append(frag)
```