# object HTMLImageElement showing instead of image

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I created an array of 2 images and tried to display them, but instead of the images I got the text:
`object HTMLImageElement`

I am sure my images are in the right directory which I am currently working with.

```
< template is="auto-binding">
   <section flex horizontal wrap layout>

    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <my-panel>{{item}}</my-panel>
    </template>

</section>
```

```
  <script>
  (function() {
    addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        var createImage = function(src, title) {
              var img   = new Image();
              img.src   = src;
              img.alt   = title;
              img.title = title;
              return img; 
            };


    var items = [];

    items.push(createImage("images/photos/1.jpeg", "title1"));
    items.push(createImage("images/photos/2.jpeg", "title2"));

    CoreStyle.g.items = items;

      addEventListener('template-bound', function(e) {
        e.target.g = CoreStyle.g;
        e.target.items = items;
      });
    });

  })();
  </script>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you appending it to the DOM anywhere?

Comment: You need to use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild). How are you inserting it to DOM? Please provide code.

Comment: "got the text", how, exactly?  In the quoted code you're not displaying or outputting or doing anything visual with the results of `createImage`.

Comment: your `Image()` is an object, when you convert it to string and print on your page it will do a simple `.toString()` and you will obviously receive `object HTMLImageElement`... if you want it to be appended correctly to the html, either use a built in append function or take the inner html of the image and append that

Comment: @Banana You mean `outerHTML` - images can't have `innerHTML` ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes thats what i meant :p thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display image through html image element object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876558/display-image-through-html-image-element-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and safest way to do this is to put the img in the template and bind the `src` and `title` attributes like this:

```
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
  <my-panel><img src="{{item.src}}" alt="{{item.title}}" title="{{item.title}}"></my-panel>
</template>
```

Then `createImage` looks like this

```
var createImage = function(src, title) {
  return {src: src, title: title};
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
items.push(createImage(...).outerHTML);
```

**Edit**: Changes to original question has rendered the rest of the answer obsolete. But I am leaving it anyway in the hope that OP or someone may learn something.

> I got the text: object HTMLImageElement

I am pretty sure you are using something like this to add the new element to DOM:

```
document.getElementById('#insert_image_here').innerHTML = items[0];
```

(Edit: What happens here is this: your newly created object `items[0]` is an `HTMLImageElement`. When you try to assign it to `innerHTML`, since `innerHTML` is type of `String`, JavaScript will try to call the objects `toString()` method and set the returned value to `innerHTML`. For DOM elements `toString` always returns `object XElement`.)

What you need to do is this:

```
document.getElementById('#insert_image_here').appendChild(items[0]);
```

Comment: @user3764893: I updated the answer. If you still insist on using the array of Image objects try replacing `<my-panel>{{item}}</my-panel>` with `<my-panel>{{item.outerHTML}}</my-panel>` (I don't know a thing about polymer. But it looks like it can execute JavaScript. So I'm not even sure if this will introduce an error. But try it anyway.)

Comment: yeah I tried with the both ways you suggested and it now shows only `images/photos/1.jpeg" alt="title1" title="title1">` ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    var createImage = function(src, title) {
          var img   = new Image();
          img.src   = src;
          img.alt   = title;
          img.title = title;
          return img; 
        };
```

With

```
var createImage = function(src,title) {
    title = title.replace(/"/g,"&quot;");
    return '<img src="'+src+'" title="'+title+'" alt="'+title+'" />';
}
```

It looks like whatever framework thingy you're using is expecting strings, not `Image` objects ;)

Comment: But that would give me only strings. I need `Image` objects

Comment: That makes sense :). Any suggestion on how to create array of images and display them?