# '[object HTMLImageElement]' displaying instead of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code I tried to modify and put in a wrapper div. This works perfectly.

```
display_element.append($('<div>', {
    html: trial.a_path_west,
    id: 'jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'
}));
```

But this isn't working. In particular the div html part displays [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the actual image.

```
to_add+="<div id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'>" + trial.a_path_west + "</div>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: the html attribute doesn't exist for div, can you give us a little more information by what your trying to do? what do you want to happen by setting html= trial.a_path_west

Comment: Could you maybe post a jsfiddle showing the problem you are having?

Comment: trial.a_path_west is an image/stimulus I am trying to display.

Comment: So let me make sure I've got this correct, you have an image, who's source is determined through js, and you're wrapping that image in a div(presumably for styling purposes). If so, why are you displaying the path as text for the div?

Comment: trial.a_path_west is an image. What is the proper way to display it in the div then?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `html` attribute for the `div` tag.

The `html` when used in the `{}` version will invoke the `html` jquery method on it.

To do it that way you will have to add the html between the opening and closing tags of the `div`

```
to_add+="<div id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'>" +trial.a_path_west+ "</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I Think I understand what you're trying to do and what your problem is. When you're using `"<div id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'>" + trial.a_path_west + "</div>"` you're casting your image object as a string.

Instead use a jquery method such as `html` that will accept the image object as a parameter and generate the necessary html

```
if (!trial.west_is_html) {
      to_add+="<img src="+trial.a_path_west+ " id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'>";
}
else {
     var wrapper = $("<div id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'></div>");
     wrapper.html(trial.a_path_west);
     to_add+= wrapper.html();
}
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wXV3u/) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876558/display-image-through-html-image-element-object) for a working example and more information